# redhat satellite + downgrade procedure - how

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, satellite, rhn

I used the RHN -  red-hat satellite version 5.x in order to install errata patch: ( on linux version 6.x ) 
    glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64

while the curent patch on my linux was:

```
glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
```

WITH RHN the patch installed successfully.

But now I want to return to the previous patch version -

```
 glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
```

Please advise how can I perform downgrade process with RHN?

What are the steps required in order to perform the downgrade?

---

from my linux machine:

```
# yum history info | tail -5
    Updated glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64   @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Update              2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64   @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Updated glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Update                2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64 @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    history info
```

Comment: This turns out to be a difficult problem. [Red Hat recommends against using Satellite to rollback kernel and glibc updates.](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/24942) And using yum manually is [possible](https://access.redhat.com/node/29617), but you lose the benefits of automation...